# Bloquear ejecución de window.open()

Tags: javascript, ventana

Como ya muchos sabréis en algunas páginas hay ventanas emergentes que se abren en una nueva ventana sin la mayoría de herramientas del navegador.

He llegado a la conjetura de que se debe a la ejecución de la función window.open() en JavaScript.

¿Habría alguna manera de prohibirla ejecutando JavaScript? ¿O alguna otra forma?

```
window.open("", "ventana1", "height=200,width=700,left=300,location=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=yes,top=300" );
```

Muchas gracias de ante manano.

Comment: Los navegadores por defecto bloquean las ventanas emergentes si no ha habido interaccion alguna primero con la pagina, es decir, no se ha interactuado con algun periferico en la pagina, por ejemplo clicks del mouse o tecleos, sin embargo... para que querrias bloquear este comportamiento en tu propia pagina?, es decir, a menos de que tu mismo en tu pagina hagas uso de este metodo no se te van a abrir ventanas emergentes, acaso quieres prevenir anuncios o cosas asi pero de otras paginas??, cual es tu objetivo?

Comment: Yo tengo una forma poco recomendada, pero que serviria perfecto y como anillo al dedo en caso de que lo que quieras prevenir son anuncios

Comment: Creo que te estas refiriendo al uso de la característica `modal=yes` de window.open combinada con `menubar=no`, etc. Eso no se como lo puedes impedir si te refieres a páginas que no son tuyas. Supongo que siempre puedes ver cual es la url leyendo el código javascript si no esta oculto de algun modo o interpretado dinámicamente desde un backend con severas restricciones de acceso externo.

Comment: Es para bloquear los anuncios emergentes usando una extensión de Chrome. La extensión tiene la posibilidad de ejecutar código JavaScript dentro de las paginas por lo que si resuelvo de que manera se puede con JavaScript podre ejecutarlo @Riven

Comment: @masterguru soy consiente de que se puede hacer de esa manera pero me gustaría hacerlo haciendo que sean las ejecuciones las que no lancen el script.

Comment: Agrega esa información de contexto a la pregunta.  Si lo llego a saber no comento nada pues no tengo ni idea de extensiones de navegadores y no se su alcance. No se si es posible ver el codigo fuente de otras extensiones que hagan cosas similares, yo quizás tiraria por ahí.

Comment: Intenta setear el metodo `open` de `window` a `null`, es la peor cosa que puedes llegar a hacer, pero creo que es la forma mas segura de hacer que no se llegue a abrir absolutamente ninguna venta, ahora bien, si quieres permitir alguna u otra ventana tendras que hacer un control personalizado bastante mas complejo... de todas maneras nunca he hecho codigo para extensiones ni tampoco se como crearlas, asi que esa parte deberas probarla tu

Comment: Gracias @Riven en cuanto tenga un hueco probaré y te digo si me funciono.

Comment: @Riven he estado investigando y no entiendo de que manera se puede setear una función predeterminada de JavaScript. ¿Me lo sabrías decir? ¿O lo has dicho como idea sin saberlo con seguridad?

Comment: @Xaival `window.open = null;`, eso haria que todas las llamadas que dependan de la funcion `window.open` fallen, tambien de una vez debes tener en cuenta que `window.open` no es la unica manera de abrir ventanas, tambien estan los `links` (`<a>`) los cuales deberias de prevenir su comportamiento por defecto para algunos de ellos (ya que no necesariamente todos son publicidad), y ahi es donde esta lo complicado,  algunos links por ejemplo hacen parte del menu de la pagina, otros son secciones, quien sabe.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Riven esto me funcionó.

Comment: Ohhh, de hecho se me olvido comentarte algo ahora que estamos, para que sea efectivo lo que acabe de decir, recuerda que al igual que existe `window.open` existen metodos alternativos e incluso según internet explorer, algunos metodos especificos viejos, en este caso deberias tambien realizar lo mismo para los metodos alternativos (si existen para `window.open`), para dar a entender a lo que me refiero es que existen varios tipos de metodos o propiedades de compatibilidad que llegan a hacer lo mismo, por ej, esta `window.URL.createObjectURL` o `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL`

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL` y su equivalente de compatibilidad es solo un ejemplo, y no tienen nada que ver con `window.open` pero si depronto encuentras un equivalente de compatibilidad para `window.open` o un equivalente experimental entonces tambien deberas bloquearlo, puesto que si la pagina esta suficientemente bien implementada puede que reconozca las compatibilidades y opte por una o varias alternativas, en cuyo caso a pesar de que bloquees `window.open` aun seguiran abriendose ventanas emergentes pero con sus demas equivalentes.